# Method that applies a background color if a certain condition is true html css angular typescript

Tags: html, css

I have an array of objects. I need to verify that if the first person's name is the same as Andrea, I need to apply the red background to the whole page. But it doesn't work for me

app.component.html

```
<body>
  <div *ngFor="let persona in persone">
    <div [ngClass]="{'body': verificaNome() }">i</div>
<body>
```

app.component.ts

```
//CREARE UN ARRAY DI OGGETTI CHE CONTIENE ARRAY DI OGGETTI
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'esercizi';

  persone: any = [
    {
      nome: 'Andrea',
      cognome: 'Pasculli',
      indirizzo: {
      via: 'Bari 1',
        },
      anni: [{
        minimo: [1,2,3],
        medio: [4,5,6],
        massimo: [7,8,9],
      }],
    },

    {
      nome: 'Chiara',
      cognome: 'Grispo',
      indirizzo: {
        via: 'Torino 5',
      },
      anni: [{
        minimo: [3,4,5],
        medio: [6,7,8],
        massimo: [9,10,11],
    }],
}]


variabile: boolean = false;

ngOnInit(){
this.verificaNome();
}

constructor(){}

verificaNome(): boolean {
  if(this.persone[0].nome=="Andrea"){
    return this.variabile = true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }


  //return false;

}

}
```

app.component.scss

```
.body{
    background-color : red;
}
```

I can't figure out where the problem is considering the logic looks right to me and I don't have any syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the background of the whole page when there's one person having the `.name === 'Andrea'` you should change the class of the body element and not of the persona element.

Here in this example I have a css rule as:

```
.red-background{
  background-color: red;
}
```

(instead of the selector you were using was `.body`).

Then in your component you should have a function that will check if in the whole `persone` array there's such an item fulfilling the condition:

```
hasPersonaNamedAndrea() {
  return this.persone.some(p => p.name === 'Andrea');
}
```

And your template:

```
<body [ngClass]="{'red-background': hasPersonaNamedAndrea()}">
  <div *ngFor="let persona of persone">
    <div>{{persona.name}}</div>
<body>
```

### Further considerations:

In your component you had the function `verificaNome()` that was doing always `if(this.persone[0].nome=="Andrea")` checking only if the first element in the array fulfilled the condition. The iteration loop index in your template didn't change anything about the state so it was not performing an action based on the currently ongoing loop iteration.

There's still the chance I made some assumptions .. maybe you didn't want ***the whole page*** to change background, and in that case it was ok to change the class of the persona div.. but surely you needed a condition actually evaluating the persona you wished to change background.